# Reverting master branch to previous state

Tags: git, branch

I have two branches: master and bonbon

Currently they are at the same point. The bonbon was a side project that was going to be released but has now been put on hold. I would like to revert the master branch to a point before the bonbon branch was created. However I would also like to keep some of the changes I made in the bonbon branch and in the future it might be required to merge back in the bonbon branch so I don't want to lose those changes. What is the best way to revert the master branch and pick out the required changes.

I tried to reset the branch but when I commited and push the changes it failed and I've ended up merging the two branches together again! Should I have done a hard push (edit: i meant force push)?

Comment: Could you please clarify the scheme? You are talking about two branches, but obviously you also have some remote repo (with unknown branches).

Comment: @Let_Me_Be sure but I'm not sure what other info you need (git is still quite fresh to me). The remote repo has 3 branches in total but one of them has already been merged into the master so I thought it would be okay to ignore it.

Comment: How does the remote repo map to your local repo? Is it just a clone?

Comment: Please define "I tried to reset the branch"?

Comment: @fge I selected the point at which I wanted to return and selected a mixed reset (leave working tree untouched, reset index)

Comment: @xylar then see my answer -- if you don't know what a fast-forward merge is, I can explain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that by resetting the branch you meant something like this, while on the `master` branch:

```
git reset --hard some_ref_below_master
```

In this case, a push will fail, because a push on a particular branch, by default, requires that the merge (of the remote branch with your local branch) is a fast forward, that is, that the remote's ref is an immediate parent to your local ref.

So, you have no other choice than to force the push -- either with `git push --force`, or with `git push +localref:remoteref` (the local ref spec can be omitted if the remote ref has the same name).

For instance:

```
git push remote +master # force local and remote master on the same commit
git push +foo:bar # force remote's bar ref to point to the same commit as local's foo
```

Comment: thanks, I repeated my previous steps, although this time I did a hard reset and force pushed to origin. I am now cherry picking those commits I needed from the bonbon branch. Do you think this will be okay when I try to merge the bonbon branch back into the master?

Comment: Yes, since this time, it will be a fast forward. Note that you could have used an interactive rebase, too.

Answer (score 3):

As for the first part of the question. If the merge with the bonbon branch is just the top commit, then you only need to reset the master branch to the state before the merge.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

If you have multiple merge points, you will have to do an interactive rebase

```
git rebase -i
```

Now as for syncing the repo with the remote. Since you have just overwritten history, git won't just allow you to commit this state. You will have to do a forced push.

```
git push --force
```

Note though that this will rewrite the history of the remote repo and anyone using this repo will have to force pull the changes.