# How to restore master branch to a previous commit

Tags: git, github

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742188/reverting-master-branch-to-previous-state) but it doesn't work for me (still shows the most recent commit as the branch head, so I remember..).
In our project git, in the master branch, a previous commit has made many files strange.
For example, (recent commit first)

```
commit_5  <-- most recent commit
commit_4  
commit_3
commit_2  <--- this commit made many files strange..
commit_1
commit_0
commit_-1
....
```

Rather than over-writing many files and make a new commit, I wanted to make the master branch point to commit 1, and commit just several files from there anew.  Following the link above, I tried (I'm on master branch)

```
git reset --hard commit_1
git push --force origin master
```

For the second command, I received `Everything up-to-data` which is not good. So I tried `git pull` from another machine and found it doesn't go to the good old commit number(commit_1).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work for me"? What does happen?

Comment: Are you on the correct branch. Also use `git push --force` without the rest.
Full console prints would be helpfull. Also relevant output from `git status` before and after each command.

Comment: You say "*I wanted to make the master branch point to commit 2*" but then you reset on `commit_1`? (If the problematic commit is `commit_2` then yes resetting on `1` makes sense.)

Comment: @Kim Thank you very much! Without the `origin master` in the push command, it worked! And in another machine, I did 'git pull origin master; git checkout origin/master'. Please write a simple answer so that I can choose it as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @evolutionxbox Hi I added in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Don't put the answer in the Question field. Put it in the Answer field! Answering your own question, and accepting your own answer, are totally legal.

Answer (score -1):

The answer was (how to restore a git to a previous commit),

```
git reset --hard commit_1
git push --force
```